# How to reduce the noise from my household washing machine

Tags: home, substitute-tool, sound

I have a washing machine in my home, once the spin cycle starts, the vibration is very annoying. I live above a tenant and he complains that he can hear the vibration above. Any suggestions on how to minimize the vibration during the spin cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as though your washing machine needs to be balanced properly.

If you've never done it, it can be a bit of a black art. The machine will normally have 2 feet at the front which can be unscrewed with a spanner to make them longer (or vice versa) to make sure the machine is sitting firmly on all four feet. If one of the feet is too short, it's a bit like a chair sitting on an uneven floor (or a restaurant table) where it keeps wobbling on the 2 longest legs and onto each of the other 2 legs in turn.

I usually find it much easier to balance it by sliding thin material like plywood, cardboard or plastic under the suspect foot until it gets better. Do it while the machine is spinning to get instant feedback. Once you establish which foot needs to be longer, you can then make the fix permanent by adjusting the foot with a spanner.

Answer (score 2):

If the tenant below is complaining, I would imagine the washing machine is perhaps shaking on a hard floor. The best way to reduce the sound of these humanoid washing machines is to place something underneath to dampen the vibrations and the sound. I suggest you use a piece of thick carpet/rug you don't care for or a rubber mat, or anything you can find that's well padded and lifts the washing machine from the floor.
It is also a god idea to ensure you have left a gap between worktops etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is making an extreme amount of noise, it probably needs balancing.There are feet under the washer that you can make come out farther or go in farther all the way around on four corners and you have to adjust those to get it level and you will hardly be able to hear it running at all,if that is the particular problem.

Comment: This answer has already been given.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with my front loader washing machine and after balance a couple of day start to walk again.

Some friend recommend to check [anti vibration pads](https://knivel.com/washing-machine-foot-pads/), it is a small piece of rubber that are magical.

Check about it..!

Comment: Preferred responses here include something that you might already have around your house (for example, if one was asking how to remove blood stains, you might suggest hydrogen peroxide rather than a fancy cleaner from the store). If there is a common around-the-house item one can substitute for this, please feel free to add that and leave the link you posted as well in case they choose to buy something to fix the problem permanently later :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the balance of the feet on each corner and adjust if required.
Check the machine is not overloaded and the contents are equally distributed when filling.
Place padding or foam spacers between the sides of the machine and housing unit in order to absorb any vibrations.

Comment: These answers have already been given.